# C# Alternative Class/Library To Using PostMessage (user32.dll) To Send Keystrokes?

Tags: c#, process, send, keystrokes

I have an application that needs to send keystrokes to another process. I have had limited success using the *PostMessage* function defined in *user32.dll*. I can send *normal* keystrokes but I cannot send keystrokes with modifiers (eg. ALT, CTRL).

Let me show you what I currently have...

Constants:

```
public const ushort WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
public const ushort WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
public const ushort WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;
public const ushort WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x0105;
public const ushort WM_SYSCHAR = 0x0106;
public const ushort VK_MENU = 0x12; // ALT key
```

DLL Import:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, uint wParam, int lParam);
```

Method to send a single key:

```
public static void PostKey(ushort key, IntPtr hWnd)
{
    SetActiveWindow(hWnd);
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, key, 0);
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, key, 0);
}
```

Method to send a single key along with ALT (doesn't work):

```
public static void PostKeyWithAlt(ushort key, IntPtr hWnd)
{
    SetActiveWindow(hWnd);
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_MENU, 0);
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, key, 0);
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSKEYUP, key, 0);
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_MENU, 0);
}
```

*PostKey* works flawlessly. I am able to connect to another process, get the main window handle, and send any arbitrary keystroke I want.

The problem arises when I try to use *PostKeyWithAlt*. This just doesn't seem to work. (The key gets sent but not the ALT so it's basically the same as *PostKey*.) I have Googled and tried so many combinations of method calls I am quite frankly ready to call it quits. :P

So, in desperation, I used the Visual Studio Spy++ tool to watch what happens when I hit ALT+F1 in the target application. Here is the result of the message capture:

Spy++ Log:

```
<00001> 00080228 P WM_SYSKEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_MENU cRepeat:1 ScanCode:38 fExtended:0 fAltDown:1 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<00002> 00080228 P WM_SYSKEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_F1 cRepeat:1 ScanCode:3B fExtended:0 fAltDown:1 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<00003> 00080228 P WM_SYSKEYUP nVirtKey:VK_F1 cRepeat:1 ScanCode:3B fExtended:0 fAltDown:1 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
<00004> 00080228 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_MENU cRepeat:1 ScanCode:38 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
```

As you can see, the sequence is exactly the same sequence as my *PostKeyWithAlt* function. So I would think that it would work but it's not.

There must be something else going on here. The only thing I can think of is the 4th parameter to the *PostMessage* function. According to the Microsoft documentation this 4th parameter is defined as *LPARAM lParam* (see below for the full function definition of *PostMessage*).

Perhaps I need to be setting *lParam* to something other than 0? If so, what value(s) do I need to set? Can I use the Spy++ log to figure it out? If so, it's beyond me how to interpret anything past _nVirtKey:VK_MENU_ in those log messages:

```
<00001>.... cRepeat:1 ScanCode:38 fExtended:0 fAltDown:1 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<00002>.... cRepeat:1 ScanCode:3B fExtended:0 fAltDown:1 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<00003>.... cRepeat:1 ScanCode:3B fExtended:0 fAltDown:1 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
<00004>.... cRepeat:1 ScanCode:38 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
```

If I could translate the log messages above to the correct *lParam* argument it just might work.

Any help/suggestions on how to do so would be greatly appreciated.

Alternatively, is there is another more elegant way to send keystrokes to a process? Perhaps a C# library? I know about the *SendKeys* class but that class doesn't send keystrokes to other applications.

Thanks!

PostMessage Function Definition:

```
BOOL WINAPI PostMessage(
  _In_opt_  HWND hWnd,
  _In_      UINT Msg,
  _In_      WPARAM wParam,
  _In_      LPARAM lParam
);
```

Comment: Don't get your hopes up, but perhaps [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) will be helpful...

Comment: Never tried _API Monitor_. Will look into it right now. Thanks!

Comment: also take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384669/sending-right-altc-with-postmessage