# Alt+key not working with PostMessage(use32.dll)

Tags: c#, postmessage, user32

I read this answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384669/sending-right-altc-with-postmessage)

It is exactly what i tring to do,i need to send postmessage  Alt+'E' to winApp but it's not working i used Spy++ and duplicate Wparametr and Lparametr and build it with postmessage.
I did the same but i can't get the Alt+E action.

Any one know where is my misstake?
How to get Alt+E event/action  form windows application?

Here Spy++ the first 5 rows i pressed and the second is my code.(see the diffrance in Lparametrs and extend and AltDown)

In Img you can see that my code send's different Lparam.

[image]

Here my code

```
private const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
private const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
private const uint WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;
private const uint WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x0105;
private const int VK_MENU = 0x12;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int PostMessage(int hWnd, UInt32 msg, int wParam, int lParam);
//Here i take all Lparametrs from Spy++
PostMessage(Main, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_MENU, 20380001);
PostMessage(Main, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, 0x45, 20120001);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
PostMessage(Main, WM_SYSKEYUP, 0x45, 0xE0120001);
PostMessage(Main, WM_KEYUP, VK_MENU, 0xC0380001);
```

Comment: You used values as decimal but Spy++ used hexa. You need use prefix "0x", so instead of 20380001 you need to use 0x20380001 and instead of 20120001 you need to use 0x20120001

Comment: I tried with 0x20380001 to,but it just selecting the tabs like Alt was pressed,but there is no real event, i read that apllication read the keyboard  with SetKeyboardState(),and it acually checking if button pressed sow combination Alt+e don't work ,any way i did this another way with clicking on tab that i need and it works.Thanx any way.